# Imported SVG with <img> tags disappearing when wrapped in <a> tags?

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

I am using React to import several SVG images into a component. I am then rendering the images inside `<img>` tags which works as expected.

```js
import React from 'react';

// Icons
import linkedin from './icons/linkedin.svg';
import stackoverflow from './icons/stackoverflow.svg';

const icons = [
  {
    data: linkedin,
    string: 'Linkedin',
    url: 'https://google.com/'
  },
  {
    data: stackoverflow,
    string: 'Stack Overflow',
    url: 'https://google.com'
  },
];

const mapIcons = icons.map((icon, index) => (
  <img key={index} src={icon.data} alt={icon.string} />
));

const IconContainer = () => (
 <div>
  {mapIcons}
 </div>
);

export default IconContainer;
```

However, when I wrap the `<img>` tags with `<a>` tags, the SVG's just disappear. Same thing happens if I use `<object>` tags.

```js
const mapIcons = icons.map((icon, index) => (
  <a href={icon.url} target="_blank">
    <img key={index} src={icon.data} alt={icon.string} />
  </a>
));
```

This problem doesn't exist with inline SVG but I prefer `<img>` tags as I don't want to fill my component with a bunch of SVG. Has anyone ever encountered this before or know of a solution?

Comment: check this out, I can see no problem in your code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vgysui . or explain a bit more to solve this

Comment: Here is my project: [Link to Project](https://github.com/joelhoelting/blog-gatsby/blob/master/src/components/Logo/IconContainer/index.js). It must be an issue with my styles

Comment: yes this is a style issue. check the above link, just updated your styles with your code,

Comment: Thanks for looking into this for me, seems like the issue was `flex: 1 0 0` needed to be applied to the `<a>` tag. Please leave an answer and I will mark it as answered. Thank you!

Comment: Glad !!! it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With our old conversation, just updated your styles with flex, check the below link.

Thanks

[demo](http://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vgysui)